# My images Jump half way down on Fixed header

Tags: jquery, css, image, fixed

I am baffled,

I have created a fixed header (yellow bar) that snaps into place (underneath black bar) using jquery,

It works great, the only problem is that the first images jump half way down the page when the (yellow bar snaps into place)

It is vital this is a smooth process as the user wont be able to view the first few images correctly.

I have added a fiddle to simulate what is happening on my website, although on the site the jumping is a lot worse. please view the fiddle and you can see the images jump slightly up when they hit the yellow bar.

I hope this makes sense. Appreciate all the help !,

couldnt do this without the great support !!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/f95sW/6/

Cheers

Paul

```
var offset = $(".sticky-header").offset();
var sticky = document.getElementById("sticky-header")
var additionalPixels = 50;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > offset.top - additionalPixels) {
        $('.sticky-header').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.sticky-header').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fixing the image "jump"

The problem is that in setting the element to `fixed` you're taking it out of the flow of the page. To adjust for this you'll need to add extra padding onto your page's `body` tag to account for the missing 30px (the height of your fixed element).

For this I've added the "fixed" class onto the body instead:

```
$('body').addClass('fixed');
```

I've then changed your CSS to retain the element's fixed position by changing `.fixed` to `.fixed .sticky-header`:

```css
.fixed .sticky-header { ... }
```

I've then added `padding-top` to `body.fixed` which is equal to the height of your fixed element:

```css
body.fixed {
    padding-top:30px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/f95sW/9/).

### Additional fix

It's worth bearing in mind that as the red bar on top is also fixed, you'll also need to account for the height of this too to prevent it overlapping the blue "container" divider. I've done that for you in [this updated JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/f95sW/10/):

```css
body {
    padding-top:52px; /* Red bar height */
    margin:0; /* Clear default browser margin */
}

body.fixed {
    padding-top:82px; /* Red bar height + yellow bar height */
}
```

Comment: appreciate your help !! do you take on freelance work? do you have an email i can contact you on?

Comment: Happy to help! Unfortunately I'm too busy at the moment to take on any more work. Please remember to upvote and mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. :)